# Set default value unchecked (checkbox) to value=10 (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

Set default value uncheck (checkbox) to value=10 (JQuery).

If i unchecked i would to set value=10 of all every unchecked (check-box).

How to do that ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If checkbox value is to be set on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkboxclass:not(:checked)").val("10");
});
```

If checkbox value is to be set on checkbox click:

```
$(".checkboxclass").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).val("10");
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }
});
```